# how to read a nul-terminated-string from a binary file

Tags: shell, files, string, binary

I have a binary file that is filled with `FF` values. I filled its start with many `\000`. Then, I padded its start with 10 `\000`, in order to get some kind of offset, and then I wrote a shorter string, also terminated with `\000`

I used this `printf`:

`printf \000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000MAC_ADDRESS=12:34:56:78:90,PCB_MAIN_ID=m/SF-1V/MAIN/0.0,PCB_PIGGY1_ID=n/SF-1V/PS/0.0,CSL_HW_VARIANT=D\000' > eeprom`

This is how it looks like when I show the hexdump of the file

[image]

Now what I want to know is how can I read the string. I can use `MY_STR=${eeprom:OFFSET}` (`eeprom` is the file name) which will give me the string, but will also give me the rest of the file which I don't want. How can I stop it when it first encounters `\000`?

- Can't use `MY_STR=${eeprom:OFFSET:LENGTH}` because string's length is unknown
- Another thing - how can I fill it up again with `FF`?
- Using `sh` (busybox)

**EDIT**

Trying to do some minor example of this...
I have one file `input` with this values (after `xxd -c 1 input`):

```
0000000: 68  h
0000001: 65  e
0000002: 6c  l
0000003: 6c  l
0000004: 6f  o
0000005: 2c  ,
0000006: 20
0000007: 00  .
0000008: 69  i
0000009: 74  t
000000a: 27  '
000000b: 73  s
000000c: 20
000000d: 6d  m
000000e: 65  e
000000f: 2c  ,
0000010: 00  .
```

and I have this script `s.sh`:

```
BUF=""
for c in $(xxd -p input); do
    if [ "${c}" != 00 ]; then
        BUF="$BUFc";
    else
        break;
    fi
done

echo $BUF
```

and I expected it to echo "hello", however, nothing is printed

Comment: busybox's `sh` doesn't sound like something that would work well with NUL-separated data. Zsh or even Bash would better. Or some actual programming language, like Perl. Are there any other tools than busybox you can use?

Comment: `strings` will extract null terminated strings from binary files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: Direct Variable Assignment

If all you're worried about are the null bytes then you should just be able to directly read the data from the file into a variable using whichever standard method you prefer, i.e. you should be able to just ignore the null bytes and read the data from the file. Here's an example using the `cat` command and command substitution:

```
$ data="$(cat eeprom)"
$ echo "${data}"
MAC_ADDRESS=12:34:56:78:90,PCB_MAIN_ID=m/SF-1V/MAIN/0.0,PCB_PIGGY1_ID=n/SF-1V/PS/0.0,CSL_HW_VARIANT=D
```

This worked for me inside of a BusyBox Docker container.

### Solution 2: Using `xxd` and a `for` loop

If you want more control than you can use `xxd` to convert the bytes to hexadecimal strings and iterate over these strings. Then, while iterating over these string, you can apply whatever logic you'd like, e.g. you could explicitly skip over the initial null values and print the rest of the data until you reach some break condition.

Here's a script that specifies a "white-list" of valid characters (ASCII 32 through 127), treats any subsequence of other characters as a separator, and extracts all valid substrings:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# get_hex_substrings.sh

# Get the path to the data-file as a command-line argument
datafile="$1"

# Keep track of state using environment variables
inside_padding_block="true"
inside_bad_block="false"

# NOTE: The '-p' flag is for "plain" output (no additional formatting)
# and the '-c 1' option specifies that the representation of each byte
# will be printed on a separate line
for h in $(xxd -p -c 1 "${datafile}"); do

    # Convert the hex character to standard decimal
    d="$((0x${h}))"

    # Case where we're still inside the initial padding block
    if [ "${inside_padding_block}" == "true" ]; then
        if [ "${d}" -ge 32 ] && [ "${d}" -le 127 ]; then
            inside_padding_block="false";
            printf '\x'"${h}";
        fi

    # Case where we're passed the initial padding, but inside another
    # block of non-printable characters
    elif [ "${inside_bad_block}" == "true" ]; then
        if [ "${d}" -ge 32 ] && [ "${d}" -le 127 ]; then
            inside_bad_block="false";
            printf '\x'"${h}";
        fi

    # Case where we're inside of a substring that we want to extract
    else
        if [ "${d}" -ge 32 ] && [ "${d}" -le 127 ]; then
            printf '\x'"${h}";
        else
            inside_bad_block="true";
            echo
        fi
    fi
done

if [ "${inside_bad_block}" == "false" ]; then
    echo
fi
```

Now we can test this out by creating an example file which has both `\x00` and `\xff` subsequences separating substrings:

```
printf '\x00\x00\x00string1\xff\xff\xffstring2\x00\x00\x00string3\x00\x00\x00' > data.hex
```

And here's the output we get when running the script:

```
$ sh get_hex_substrings.sh data.hex
string1
string2
string3
```

### Solution 3: Using the `tr` and `cut` commands

You could also try using the `tr` and `cut` commands to deal with the null bytes. Here's an example of extracting the first null-terminated string from a list of null-terminated strings by squeezing/collapsing adjacent null-characters and converting them to newlines:

```
$ printf '\000\000\000string1\000\000\000string2\000\000\000string3\000\000\000' > file.dat
$ tr -s '\000' '\n' < file.dat | cut -d$'\n' -f2
string1
```

Comment: How would it handle the `FF` bytes? and what if there will be other garbage values after the null byte that ends the string?

Comment: @CIsForCookies The first method (`dat="$(cat eeprom)"` probably won't work for that case, but the loop obviously will - you can include whatever logic you want in there. Maybe update your question to include a more complete input example along with the desired output?

Comment: Can you please explain the `xxd` parameters? can't understand why `-c` is needed (the others I'm not sure about)

Comment: @CIsForCookies The `-c` parameter sets the number of columns used when outputting. Using `-c 1` should mean that each byte is printed on its own line. I don't think it's necessary, strictly speaking - just a personal choice. Anyway, I'll update my post.